# How to input a pipe using python subprocess

Tags: python

I am having trouble correctly inputting these commands into pythons subprocess

`git status -vv | awk 'NR>8 {print last} {last=$0}'`

and

`FNR==NR{if($0~/modified/){line=FNR};next} FNR<=line || FNR>(line+4)`

currently my code is:

```
gcommit = sb.Popen(['git', 'status', '-vv', '|', 'awk',  "'NR>8 {print last} {last=$0}'"])
```

but it gives me an error at the pipe

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character isn't an argument to the `git` command, it's a shell metacharacter. If you want the shell to process the command, you need to combine it into a single string and use `shell=True`.

```
gcommit = sb.Popen("git status -vv | awk 'NR>8 {print last} {last=$0}'", shell=True)
```